# ListBox.DisplayMemberPath doesn't work as expected. How can I debug this?

Tags: wpf, debugging, data-binding

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

`DisplayMemberPath` doesn't work, and ListBox shows default `ToString` result of the `Commands` collection members. Is it possible to debug this, for example, by printing some information to Output window?

Visual Studio 2010, WPF application project. Binding is successful, and I see all members of the `Commands`collection. But display is wrong.

Additional information. If I change `Path=Commands` to non-existing `Path=Commands1`, I see error messages in the Output window. But there is no any information about error in `DisplayMemberPath`.

Comment: does your class implement a property named `Name`?

Comment: @Jehof - yes, of course. I am interesting here to learn, how can I debug such situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DisplayMemberPath` *does* work... are you sure that you're using it correctly? You can find an example of it on the [ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) page at MSDN. For your example code to work, you would need to have a public `Name` property on the data type in the `Commands` object.

Failing that, WPF errors generally get output into the Visual Studio Output window. If you do not see any errors there, check that you have the options set correctly:

Go to Tools > Options > Debugging tab > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings

You should have at least one of these options (like Data Binding) set to either Warning, Error, All, Critical or Verbose to receive error information.

Comment: WPF Trace Settings, Binding is set to All. But there is nothing about DisplayMemberPath in Output window.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have a public property named `Name` in the data type that you have bound to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property?

Comment: Yes, it has such property. BTW, the question is about debugging, and not "Why it doesn't work". So, your information about WPF Trace Settings is what I am looking for, but in this case it doesn't help.

Comment: Strange, but replacing DisplayMemberPath with ItemTemplate having the same binding works. Thanks for Trace information.

Answer (score 1):

One of the clearer/cleaner ways I've come across for debugging binding errors in WPF is often linked (but using an older, broken link) and can currently be found here: http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486#.UhyT8fNwbs0

Specifically, the approach that uses a debugging feature introduced in .Net 3.5, using the attached property `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel` and allows you to specify a particular trace level to investigate your binding issues.

Summarising here:

You add the following namespace:

```
<Window
<!-- Window Code -->
xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
/>
```

And in your binding expression, set the attached property. In my example, I'm using a list of `Cars` objects with a `Name` property, and have incorrectly listed the `DisplayMemberPath` as `Names`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" DisplayMemberPath="Names" />
```

This results in the following message in the Output window (occurring multiple times, one for each failed binding):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Names' property not found on 'object' ''Car' (HashCode=59988153)'. BindingExpression:Path=Names; DataItem='Car' (HashCode=59988153); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

The whole link is worth a read, but that's the gist of a particular technique I had success with (in case the link dies).

Comment: This gives a lot of information, but nothing about DisplayMemberPath in my case. Interesting that replacing DisplayMemberPath with ItemTemplate works.

Comment: How odd, that would seem to imply that the binding is actually working (DisplayMemberPath is correct), but there's a problem with the template somehow o.O

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Property "Name" of your "Commands" Item, plese use the following

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommandsItem, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Where `SelectedCommandsItem` is a property of your model that strictly defines a type of the collection items